Field History Tracking on User Object
I don't see an option to track field history on the User object.  Is it possible?  If so, what are the steps?  I see old Idea Exchange questions asking for this ability.  I don't see a resolution.

It's not possible, but as I type (24 May 2024) they say it's under development.

Thank you all for your feedback; as you
saw, this is one of the prioritization winners from the last round. We
have started development. However, I want to be transparent that this
is not a small effort, so we are still several releases away from
getting this into your hands. We are also in somewhat of uncharted
territory with the user while stored as data is a setup entity and
field history tracking has never really been enabled on setup entities
previously, so I can't guarantee we won't hit snags, but we will keep
updating you on progress."

